# How to automate a test that queries from a large database? (import or create)

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

Say I have the following scenario (and obviously I oversimplify it): A 'Manager' in a 'Department' 'Approves' 'Expenses' of 'Employees'.

My test here is to test a Query that returns the followings: All expenses above $X for all managers from department 'HR' between D1 and D2 etc...

I realized there are 2 approches to do this:

1. Start from scratch - create a User/Group User, add permissions, create level of security, add expenses and test your query.
2. Import a database that already has some data and test that the return result is just like what you expect to get?

Problem with option 1 is that it takes so long to 'create the environment' in order to test it.

problem with option 2 is that it takes so long to 'import' a 1GB (or more) database and then simply run your query and see if the expected result are correct.

I was wondering if there's a 3rd approach? or any improvement to the existing alternative above.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/intro.html) - it's a library designed to facilitate database testing.  The approach I usually take is to write some code in a main method which will generate the test data I need in .csv files (one per table) and then use [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) to create in-memory tables populated with this data.

This typically looks something like:

```
public static void main(final String args) {
  final DatabaseConnection conn = new DatabaseConnection(getConnectionToDbWithRealData());
  final QueryDataSet dataset = new QueryDataSet(conn);
  dataset.addTable("foo", "select * from foo where bar = 'xyz'");
  new CsvDataSetWriter(getOutputFile()).write(dataset);
}
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  ...
) AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('classpath:/foo.csv', null, 'null=null');
```

It should take an hour or so to get your dataset created, but then you can re-generated it on demand in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A third option could be to test it on a smaller database, obviously, unless you're doing some performance testing. If you go this way, you might as well try and use a small in-memory db to reduce the performance cost to test your queries.

For big queries that are noit destructive (really only *read* info in the database), then you don't necessaraily have to recreate the db every time - your test might "assume" that a database exists, at a well-known location, that is only infrequently created.

Also, as always, don't hesitate to test as much of your system as possible against a "mock" db, especially if you really want to test :

- how the query parameters are set
- what the query looks like in the end
- or how the query result is handled,
- etc... rather than how the query is actually run by your db engine.